# PowerBI Embedded DMTS_DatasourceHasNoCredentialError

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have create a PBIX file in PowerBI Desktop using DirectQuery method on Azure SQL Server. After that I uploaded the file to workspace. Now when I am opening that report on my custom web app using MVC API, it is throwing me following error:

Datasource has no credentials.
Please try again later or contact support and provide the following details to help resolve your issue faster.

```
Error CodeDMTS_DatasourceHasNoCredentialError
Server someserver.database.windows.net
Correlation ID3b3d08d7-21cd-7a4b-3778-79841050d3c4
ConnectionType {FieldValue}
Activity ID24480fac-d172-e3a6-17b6-eb8a2ce5b02c
Request IDb1ec1b45-5a65-c642-3fa0-4c5090102720
TimeFri Jun 10 2016 14:53:01 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Version13.0.1500.198
Cluster URI https://wabi-south-east-asia-redirect.analysis.windows.net/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you import your PBIX file into your Power BI workspace collection on Azure the service does not include your credentials due to security concerns.  After your import is complete you can modify the credentials and / or connection strings using our REST APIs.

[Power BI REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt712303.aspx)

Specifically you'll need to **call the PATCH datasource API**
[Patch Gateway Datasource API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt711498.aspx)

Examples of calling these APIs via the SDKs can be found in the following:

1. [.NET Provision Tool from sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/power-bi-embedded-integrate-report-into-web-app/) ([Update Connection](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/power-bi-embedded-integrate-report-into-web-app/blob/master/ProvisionSample/Program.cs))
2. [Node JS Command Line tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Cli) ([Update Connection](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Cli/blob/master/lib/cli-update-connection.ts))

Comment: P.S. I hope there will be more intuitive/easy/discoverable ways to do this stuff in the near future, because at the moment - embedding power bi reports into my own application is hard - plenty of searching, trying, guessing - not an easy stuff as I expected based on what was stated from the team